# SSH into EC2 instance stalling OS Mojave

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, macos-mojave

I have read several stackoverflow posts, but none seem to help.
I want to ssh into my ec2 instance, so I downloaded the private key file as stated in the instructions from aws. After executing "sudo ssh -v -i  ubuntu@", my ssh server hangs with no success or failure message.

I made sure my ec2 instance can accept ssh connections and that my private key file does have the correct permissions. Any other debugging steps to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Are you able to Telnet the machine from your local? `telnet <IP> 22`

Comment: telnet is not included in mojave. How would that help ?

Comment: Telnet simply let connect to a remote machine over a given port. Mostly used to verify connectivity before considering application/service issue. In your case to make sure you can connect to the server and there are no funny NACL/SG blocking happening. You can try `ping` that's usually blocked by SG.

Comment: Is your IP number (not on the local WAN, but your router's IP number) configured in your AWS security group inbound settings? When editing the inbound rules, there is a "My IP" option, which you can use so you don't have to type in your IP number in manually. See [Security group rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/console/ec2/security-groups#security-group-rules).

Comment: Do you use custom vpc or launched your instance in a default vpc?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way, the SSH hangs is when you haven't configured your Public IP to reach the ec2. Or the EC2 is not in a public subnet.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne ping resolved to icmp_seq timeout.

Comment: @Rob Adding my ip to the inbound rules allowed me to establish a connection. However, now I get the Permission denied (publickey) error.

Comment: @Marcin It is in a default VPC

Comment: @LuigiLopez Could you expand on that please.

Comment: @IsaacBuitrago Add to your question: Inbound rules of the security group of the instance, information of the subnet of the instance as (route table routes)

Answer (score 1):

When an SSH connection times-out, it is normally an indication that network traffic is not getting to the Amazon EC2 instance.

Things to check:

- The instance is running **Linux**
- The instance is launched in a **public subnet**, which is defined as having a Route Table entry to points to an Internet Gateway
- The instance has a **public IP address**, which you are using for the connection
- The **Network Access Control Lists** (NACLs) are set to their default "Allow All" values
- A **Security Group** associated with the instance that permits inbound access on port 22 (SSH) either from your IP address, or from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- Your **corporate network** permits an outbound SSH connection (try alternate networks, eg home vs work vs tethered to your phone)

See also: [Troubleshooting connecting to your instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)